# EmberCLI & Handlebars rendering issue

Tags: ember.js, handlebars.js, ember-cli

I have a simple blog app written with Ruby on Rails. It provides REST API for blogs and users.

I have created Ember app using `ember-rails` gem and sprockets. Everything works: http://joxi.ru/D2PjBk6cpDwzr3

But when I migrated ember to Ember CLI I have some problems: http://joxi.ru/krDp9W7HEPGorp

In Rails console I see that it makes response but there are problems with rendering.

My code you can see here:  https://github.com/Tonkonozhenko/embernoise/tree/ember-cli/app/frontend

Comment: are you using `ember-cli-rails` now?

Comment: I have paused learning ember but I'll continue it soon